# Using a dictionary to assign misspelled words to its line number

Tags: python, dictionary, spell-checking

This is the code I currently have:

```
from collections import defaultdict

goodwords = set()

with open("soccer.txt", "rt") as f:
     for word in f.readlines():
        goodwords.add(word.strip())

badwords = defaultdict(list)

with open("soccer.txt", "rt") as f:
    for line_no, line in enumerate(f):
        for word in line.split():
            if word not in text:
                badwords[word].append(line_no)

print(badwords)
```

How can I fix my code so that it prints the incorrect words stored inside the `words` list and the line number?

For example if the word `togeher` was misspelled on lines 5 and 7, it would print something like:

```
togeher 5 7
```

Comment: You need to format the code so we could run it - I did a simple format but this misses some indents

Comment: Don't count lines; use `len(words)`.

Comment: If you get an error and want to ask a question about it, tell us *what* error you get.

Comment: the error i get is 
d[word].append(counter)

KeyError: 'a'

Answer (score 1):

When you insert the new `counter` into `d`, you check first `word` is contained in `words`. Probably you wanted to check if `word` is already contained in `d`:

```
if word not in d:
    d[word] = [counter]
else:
    d[word].append(counter)
```

The check if the `word` is contained in `words` or `line` should be a separate `if`.

You could also simplify this logic with the dicts `setdefault()` method:

```
d.setdefault(word, []).append(counter)
```

Or you make `d` a `defaultdict`, which simplifies the assignment even more:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
...
d[word].append(counter)
```

About the general algorithm note that at the moment you first iterate over all lines to increment the counter and then, when the counter has already reached it's maximum value, start checking for misspelled words. Probably you should do the checking for each line in the loop where you increment the counter.

Comment: the text file is actually called soccer.txt but im using sys.argv
ive only been programming for 2 months so im not guna understand everything .
ive changed if word not in words to
if words not in d
but i still get an error 
print(word, d[counter])
keyerror: 329

Comment: i have a list of incorrect words and want to print the line number of the incorrect word where it is in my txt file into a set so then it prints out 
helo     5     8     # 5 and 8 being the line number in the txt file 
though any suggestions on how to do that plzzzz

Answer (score 0):

Form what you are doing, I suspect that the following would suit you near perfectly:

```
from collections import defaultdict

text = ( "cat", "dog", "rat", "bat", "rat", "dog",
         "man", "woman", "child", "child") #

d = defaultdict(list)

for lineno, word in enumerate(text):
    d[word].append(lineno)

print d
```

This gives you an output of:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'bat': [3], 'woman': [7], 'dog': [1, 5],
                            'cat': [0], 'rat': [2, 4], 'child': [8, 9],
                            'man': [6]})
```

This simply sets up an empty default dictionary containing a list for each item you access, so that you don't need to worry about creating the entry, and then enumerates it's way over the list of words, so you don't need to keep track of the line number.

As you don't have a list of correct spellings, this doesn't actually check if the words are correctly spelled, just builds a dictionary of **all** the words in the text file.

To convert the dictionary to a set of words, try:

```
all_words = set(d.keys())
print all_words
```

Which produces:

```
set(['bat', 'woman', 'dog', 'cat', 'rat', 'child', 'man'])
```

Or, just to print the words:

```
for word in d.keys():
    print word
```

**Edit 3:**

I think this might be the final version:
It's a (deliberately) very crude, but almost complete spell checker.

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Build a set of all the words we know, assuming they're one word per line
good_words = set() # Use a set, as this will have the fastest look-up time.
with open("words.txt", "rt") as f:
    for word in f.readlines():
        good_words.add(word.strip())

bad_words = defaultdict(list)

with open("text_to_check.txt", "rt") as f:
    # For every line of text, get the line number, and the text.
    for line_no, line in enumerate(f):
        # Split into seperate words - note there is an issue with punctuation,
        # case sensitivitey, etc..
        for word in line.split():
            # If the word is not recognised, record the line where it occurred.
            if word not in good_words:
                bad_words[word].append(line_no)
```

At the end, `bad_words` will be a dictionary with the unrecognised words as the key, and the line numbers where the words were as the matching value entry.

Comment: i actualy do have a list of correct spelling called dictset = []
which is a dictionary of many many words however ill try this thanks
this is what i have 
a txtfile involving words 
a list of incorrect words 
and i just want to attach the lne numbers of the incorrect words to each other

Comment: what u said workd but i want it to print 
as a set 
i have a set but i can only print the words as a set

Comment: for inwords in incorrectwords:
     print(inwords)
this prints a set of my incorrect words
but how do i do that to the code you showed me ? cheers

Comment: im thankful for what uve done and believe if i add one more thing it should work 
instead of printing the line number of the incorrect word
i want to print the line number of the incorrect word located in the txt file what would i add?
i tried to add if word in txtfile:???

Comment: Updated to a minimal, but complete, example

Comment: ey thanx its working but i have incorrect words as list creates already i want to use that because im using sys.argv[] to open them 
i have a list of words and a list of incorrect words how can i replace them instead of opening the text? cheers

Comment: ive update my code above 
i got u into trouble by u not needing to create bad words and goodwords 
because i have a list of words in the txt file 
and a list of the misspeled words how can i use them cheers

Comment: You've just about got it - you just need to change the "word not in text" line to use goodwords, instaed of text, as text is not a defined variable.